# Displaying and decrementing hp based on collision detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, virtual-reality

So I have enemy gameobjects attacking a user in a small base. The enemies have an OnCollisionEnter method where it checks to see what it collides with. If it's tagged as the base, it sets an attack boolean to true, where the fixedupdate is supposed to check for that flag. When true, it calls a coroutine in which I try and call the method that removes health from the wall (this script is attached to the wall). The walls health is then displayed on a HUD I have elsewhere in the room Code Below

Problem is, enemies can't do damage to the base and the HUD remains unchanging. Any tips/help? Here is the enemy behaviour script

```
 public class EnemyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
 private GameObject target;
 private Vector3 targetPos;
 private WallBehaviour wallBehaviour;
 public GameObject collisionObject;
 private bool attackMode;
 public float speed = 0.1f;
 public int hp = 100;
 public float attackCooldown = 1.0f;
 public int attackPoints = 1;
 public float killThreshhold = 1.5f;
 public Color defaultColor;
 //Use this for initialization
 void Start() {
     target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
     targetPos = target.transform.position;
     attackMode = false;
 }
 void FixedUpdate() {
     targetPos = target.transform.position;
     transform.LookAt(target.transform);
     float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, step);
     if (attackMode)
     {
         StartCoroutine("attemptAttack");
     }
     else
     {
         GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = defaultColor;
     }
 }
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
     collisionObject = collision.gameObject;
     if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bunker") {
         wallBehaviour = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<WallBehaviour>();
         attackMode = true;
     }
 }
 public IEnumerator Attack()
 {
     attackMode = false;
     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
     wallBehaviour.ProcessDamage(attackPoints);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackCooldown);
     attackMode = true;
 }
 void ProcessDamage(int attackPoints)
 {
     hp -= attackPoints;
     if (hp <= 0)
     {
         Die();
     }
 }
 public int getHitPoints()
 {
     return hp;
 }
 public void Damage(DamageInfo info)
 {
     hp -= info.damage;
     if (hp <= 0) {
         Die();
     }
 }
 public void Die()
 {
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```

Comment: Uh...should you perhaps be calling `StartCoroutine("Attack")` and not `StartCoroutine("attemptAttack")`? Because I'm not seeing `IEnumerator attemptAttack()` anywhere.

Comment: Also you can call your coroutine using `StartCoroutine(Attack());` which allows you to add arguments to a coroutine call. This also ease the code refactoring (if you rename your coroutine, this will update as well).